# SQL Server begin count per row based on defined starting value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I am trying to provide a ID number to a column based on the last ID in said column.

EDIT: I understand there are better ways. We cannot alter this table to use a properly sequenced column so we have to make due with providing the number in the query.

For example I can use this query to get my last ID:

```
SELECT MAX(ID)
FROM TABLE
```

Results:

```
16684
```

If I use + 1 in the query then I get my starting number for the next ID:

```
SELECT MAX(ID) + 1
FROM TABLE
```

Results:

```
16685
```

I need to be able to add this to a INSERT INT0/SELECT statement so I start at the resulting number and continue the count per row provided.

For example:

```
-- I know this doesn't work I do not know what would here.
Select ID (16685), * FROM QUERY RESULTS
```

Resulting in something like:

```
16685, Data, Data, Data
16686, Data, Data, Data
16687, Data, Data, Data
16688, Data, Data, Data
16689, Data, Data, Data
...
```

I am not sure how I can provide this value.

The column in question is a SUDO ID column that was not set up properly to increment on its own so we have to provide the numbers ourselves.

Note that there will only ever be one insert per day and we are not worried about concurrent inserts happening at once.

Comment: What's wrong with using the built-in support for this, ie *identity* or *sequence*?

Comment: Doing this kind of roll your own next value is fraught with errors. The most obvious is it creates a race condition if there are multiple inserts happening at the same time. If you want an incremental integer you should identity.

Comment: @Stu as mentioned in my post this table was built flawed without a proper ID sequenced column. I am not able to have it fixed so we have to deal with the issue.

Comment: @SeanLange there will never be multiple inserts happening at the same time. We run this job daily and we are the only ones loading to this table.

Comment: Even so, using an identity would make this just work with no extra effort.

Comment: What does not able to mean though - there's nothing technically stopping you from adding an identity column to a table and setting its seed value to the next required number

Comment: @Larnu, Because this was a table that was manually loaded to until we wrote a automated solution that is owned by our team. No one else has the need nor will have the need to edit this table in the future. It is not a concern. I just need to find out how to write the logic.

Comment: Just because it's not a concern today, doesn't mean it won't be a concern tomorrow. Don't code your solutions with such a flaw in the first place; it *will* bite you in foot when you least expect it.

Comment: @Stu we just are not allowed to edit this table. Lets move past what you think should be done as we already agree that this should be done differently but we have no choice in the matter since we are not allowed to edit the table. Can we just get the logic behind defining a sequence for query results.

Comment: @SeanLange yes I understand that but am unable to have the table altered. Things are overly controlled on this database and request for changes have been denied.

Comment: Then you will either have to do your inserts in a loop and get the next value each time or if your data comes from a table you could use ROW_NUMBER and add the MAX(ID) value. Either of those approaches is brittle and likely going to cause some problems.

Comment: @SeanLange Yes I know its not the best solution and if I can convence them to fix it down the road we will use a sequenced id column but for now `row_number() over(order by <ordering criteria>) + @MaxId,` worked for me. Also that column does not (it should) take unique values only so if someone for some very strange reason does add values to the table it wont break it just cause a issue where it will likely to force them to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your next ID is already determined eg `select @MaxId = max(Id) from <table>` you could use `row_number`. I'd suggest at least using this in a serializable transaction for safety.

```
Select row_number() over(order by <ordering criteria>) + @MaxId, *... 
FROM QUERY RESULTS
```

Comment: I figured it would be a windows function based solution. I just have little experience with windows functions so was not sure of the solution. Thanks I will try this.

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @MaxId INT
SELECT @MaxId = MAX(Id)
FROM MyTable
-- in order by you can set every you want
SELECT @MaxId + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS LastId
FROM MyTable
/*
I think it is what you want
*/
```

Comment: I have a question. What is `(SELECT 0)` in this ORDER BY? I use @Stu's solution and used a specific column for the order by as its used in my main order by but I am curious what this  `(SELECT 0)` is as it does appear to work just as well as Stu's solution.

Comment: @Mike-SMT that subquery is just a way to get something for ordering. It could be anything in that query or a column to signify the order your rows.